# If any parameter is present do WHERE if both parameters are null do different WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have a stored procedure that takes in 3 parameters:

- @FKId
- @StartDate
- @EndDate

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Entity
WHERE [Entity].[FKId] = @FKId
  AND ((@StartDate IS NULL) OR (@StartDate IS NOT NULL AND [Entity].[DateFrom] >= @StartDate))
  AND ((@EndDate IS NULL) OR (@EndDate IS NOT NULL AND [Entity].[DateUntil] <= @EndDate))
```

I now want to add another part to the where clause when both `StartDate` and `EndDate` are both null I want to check if `[DateUntil]` is then greater than `GETDATE()` OR IS NULL.

The query I've tried and not sure why its not working is:

```
AND ((@StartDate IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL AND ([Entity].[DateUntil] >= GETDATE() OR ([Entity].[DateUntil] IS NULL))
```

This then seems to remove the FKId part of the clause, so I sectioned that off with brackets so it always executes that part. If the parameters are null both null it works, if both parameters have values it works, but if its a mix then it returns nothing.

I'm primarily a C# dev so expecting this to just work like an IF statement but its not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need to add the new filter 'when both StartDate and EndDate are null' with OR clause instead of AND.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh I'm using SQL Server

Comment: @tedoG that worked, cheers. Something so simple.